# python - a collatz program automate the boring stuff

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi all I have read through the previous answers to this question and can get the code to run. What I want to understand is why my code doesn't run.

Thanks

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        return number // 2
    elif number % 2 == 1:
        return 3 * number + 1

print('Enter a number')
number = int(input())

while number != 1:
    print(int(collatz(number)))
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? What isn't working? Is it the infinite loop?

Comment: So what do you think the code should do?

Answer (score 2):

You are not updating `number` in your `while` loop so you are stuck in an infinite loop.

You should assign return value of `collatz` to `number` back, to update `number`.

```
while number != 1:
    number = collatz(number)
    print(number)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response